# QT Jumping back to main screen

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qtembedded

I m new to qt.

I have one application in which there is one `QPushButton` as settings.
When settings is pressed, it shows list of buttons say A B C D E
and each button has one screen linked to it. Also each screen have back button. Means when A is pressed, screen related to A is shown and when back is pressed then user is back to list of buttons.

This is working fine.

Now I want to implement code as following :
when settings is pressed, screen related to A is shown, on screen A next button is there if that is pressed then screen B is shown, again next button is pressed then screen C is shown and so on.. at screen E next button is pressed then user should back to main screen where settings button is present.

I'm not getting when I'm on screen E and next button is pressed then how to go to main screen.

If I call close() then screen E is closed but screen D opens.

Comment: Sounds like [`QWizard`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) to do it. You can add and remove as you need.